# How to select the gpg agent used for ssh and other things?

Tags: ssh, gnupg, yubikey

I want to use `qubes-gpg-client` instead of the default gpg-agent that comes on ubuntu.

How can I make it such that ssh and other things always use this custom agent instead of the default one?